# Gas SafeLow historical data

Tags: gas, gas-price, history, ethgasstation

I am doing some gas analysis work and I really want to find or generate a dataset for historical SafeLow gas prices as defined by EthGasStation:

```
“A price that at least 5% of the network hashpower will accept. 
(I don’t want to wait for hours for a confirmation)

AND

A price that was mined within a reasonable time (< 50 blocks) the last time 
it was posted to the network as a pending transaction. 
(i.e. protect against scenario where miners were previously accepting low gas 
prices but have now changed their policies, and the transactions are no longer
confirming)”
```

SafeLow is a 50-block moving average. The ideal dataset for me would contain a daily average/median of all 50-block SafeLow's for that day and would range back to 01/01/2017.

Does anybody know of such a dataset?

I know that etherscan offers a dataset of avg gas prices, but those are always above 10gwei even when SafeLow is 1gwei. I am also aware the ethgasstation-backend is open source but I figured I'd ask this question before diving in to try to get it to do this analysis for me.